# Show that if $M$ is a compact submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ then it doesn't have an atlas with only one chart

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification

This is the exercise 14 on page 258 of *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher.

> Show that if $M$ is a non-empty compact $m$-dimensional $C^1$ submanifld of $\Bbb R^n$ with $m\ge 1$ then it dont have an atlas with only one chart.

This exercise seems wrong. Let $M:=\overline {\Bbb B_m}\times\{0\}^{n-m}\subset\Bbb R^n$ where $\Bbb B_m$ is the unit open ball centered at zero on $\Bbb R^m$. Then $M$ is a compact $m$-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ with the trivial atlas composed by the unique chart $\varphi(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m,0,\ldots,0)=(x_2,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$.

Im overlooking something or the exercise is wrong?

Comment: Your example is a [manifold with boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary) and your proposed atlas does not meet the requirements  for an atlas on such a manifold.

Comment: Does your definition of manifold allow boundary?  Typically, a manifold without boundary is open, as the union of all the open charts is an open set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the atlas of $M$ has one chart, $M$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of an Euclidean space which is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of the ball has boundary, and so it can't possible have a single chart, as Euclidean space has no boundary.